# NUnit Assert a list of objects in no order

Tags: nunit

How do I Assert a collection of items in no particular order? I just want to make sure all the items are in the list.

I'm heard of `CollectionAssert` but I do not see any method that would do what I want.

My object looks like this:

```
public class Vector2{
    public float X {get; set;}
    public float Y {get; set;}
}
```

**Assert** - I want something like this:

```
CollectionAssert.ContainsAll(mesh.GetPolygonVertices(0), aListOfVertices);
```

`mesh.GetPolygonVertices(int)` returns a `List<Vector2>` and `aListOfVertices` contains all of what is returned, but not guaranteed that order.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `AreEqual` overloads succeed if two collections contain the same objects in the same order. `AreEquivalent` tests whether collections contain the same objects regardless of their order.

http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=collectionAssert&r=2.4